# Which is a better way to say "pardon me for my bad Spanish"?

Tags: traducción

On StackOverflow, posters often say something like, "Please excuse me for my poor English."

On the Spanish version of the site, I sometimes want to write something similar. Which of the following would be preferred:

> Disculpeme por mi español bastante mala.

or:

> Perdoneme por mi español bastante mala.

or something else altogether?

Comment: "Español" is masculine, not feminine, by the way, cf "El idioma español", "mi español es malo".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

> Disculpe(n) mi pobre español

I favor `disculpar` over `perdonar` since it is a "mild" offense. To me `perdonar` has the connotation that you are looking for forgiveness while `disculpar` convey that you are just apologizing in advance for a minor inconvenience.

About

> Perdoneme por mi español bastante mala.

Remember that "bad" (malo/a) needs to agree with the noun "español", which is masculine.

Comment: I still find this answer to a very simple question useful. thank you

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to say it is,

1. Por favor disculpeme por mi pobre español. ("Please excuse me for my poor Spanish.")
2. Por favor disculpeme, mi español es muy pobre. ("Please excuse me my Spanish is poor.")
3. Por favor disculpeme, mi español es muy malo ("Please excuse me my Spanish is very bad.").

Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Disculpas, no hablo bien español.

Discúlpeme, es que no hablo muy bien el español.

Discúlpeme, es que no sé hablar bien español.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a native speaker and say it as you want, "Discúlpeme" and "perdóneme" are applied the same in this case, you can either say "Perdóneme por mi mal español" or "Discúlpeme por mi mal español".

There's also this other word which means the same as "discúlpeme" and "perdóneme" and is "Dispénseme" and of course some more variations of this depending on the region. I'm from Latin America.

Answer (score 2):

I would translate "Please excuse me for my poor English" as

*Disculpen, no se mucho español.* 
or
*Disculpen, el español no es mi lengua materna.*
or
*Disculpen, hablo un poco de español pero me queda mucho por aprender.*

In translation, it is imortant not trying to translate exactly the as in the original language but in the way peapole talks.

The translations proposed in the other responses are all strictly correct and anyone will understand you. But in general people does not speak like this.

First. In english you almost always adds "please" when you asks for something. In spanish it is not common. You only use please (por favor) when the other person really will need to do something for you.

Second, you should use "perdón" when you are sorry for hurting someoane or for breaking the granny's vase. In this case, it is better to "scuse" saying "disculpe".

Then, I thing it is better:
Disculpen, no se mucho español.

Note conjugation of the second person (you) is different in Latin America and Spain. 

In Latin America:
you excuse me 

Between friends:
*if one person -> tu discúlpame



if many persons -> ustedes discúlpenme*

In formal speaking:
*if one person -> usted discúlpame



if many persons -> ustedes discúlpenme*

In Spain:

Between friends:
*if one person -> tu discúlpame

if many persons -> **vosotros disculpadme***

In formal speaking:
*if one person -> usted discúlpame

if many persons -> ustedes discúlpenme*



... and remember that in spanish all the nouns has genere. And the language names are "male". Then español is "malo", not "mala".

Comment: *usted discúlpame* is not idiomatic. That should be *usted discúlpeme* or *tú discúlpame.*

Comment: First, thanks for your answer; I couldn't help noticing this, though: "in the way peapole talks" which makes me think of a beanstalk, and Jack, and smellable Englishmen, etc.